# Remove entries from chronicle

Tags: java, chronicle

I am working on a [ad-hoc real-time stream processing framework](https://github.com/ottogroup/SPQR/) which internally uses the [java-chronicle](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/) library to exchange data between building blocks.

The chronicle uses disk space to store items appended to the queue and increases in space with each new message.

As I consume messages just for once - replay behavior is backed by kafka outside the processing elements - processed elements may be removed and thus disk space cleaned. Is there a way to free space consumed by chronicle files simply by removing entries from it?

The alternative approach would be to open new chronicles after a fixed number of messages plus keeping track on already consumed chronicles which are then removed from disk. ...but that does not seem to be a very smooth solution ;-)

So, my question is if there is an approach on removing processed/tail'ed entries from a chronicle?

Answer (score 1):

You can now detect when a cycle is rotated and delete old files. e.g. once a day.

The assumption is that the cost of disk space is cheap, although this is not always correct.